# Firebase denies permission after first time then works on second time

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Firebase denies permission after the first time to push data to realtime database... but then works when I push data on the second time...

```
export const writeClass = async (
  courseId,
  topicName,
  classIntro,
  youtubeLinkId,
  classNoteLink
) => {

  const dbRef = ref(getDatabase());
  try {
    const totalClasses = await get(
      child(dbRef, `Courses/${courseId}/totalClasses`)
    );
    var totalClassesNum = parseInt(totalClasses.val()) + 1;
    console.log(totalClasses.val());

    const msg = await update(
      ref(db, `Courses/${courseId}/classes/${totalClassesNum}`),
      {
        classIntro: classIntro,
        topicName: topicName,
        youtubeLinkId: youtubeLinkId,
        classNoteLink: classNoteLink,
      }
    )
      .then(() => {
        update(ref(db, `Courses/${courseId}`), {
          totalClasses: totalClassesNum,
        });
        console.log("Section added");
        return true;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error.message);
        // alert(error.message)
        return error.message;
      });
  return msg;

  } catch (error) {
    // alert(error.message)

    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

The firebase rules :

```
".write" :
"root.child('specialUsers').child(auth.uid).child('is_admin').val()
=== true
```

Comment: Can you share some code where you're facing this ?

Comment: Okay... I edited the post

Comment: Are you sure the user is already signed in when you execute the write for the first time? You can most easily verify that by adding `console.log(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)` right before the write operation./

Comment: Yea, I am sure it's signed in on the first attempt. At first, when I press submit error shows permission denied and then I press submit again changing nothing, it successfully submits.

Comment: can you also verify that `courseId` is set? Is it possible that the variable is being set between the clicks? I would also echo that to console on the first line.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen why this is happening ?
when i click for the first time the console log of uid comes this:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'uid')
    at writeClass (main.chunk.js:663)
    at async handleSubmit
The second time the  uid logs on the console...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase automatically restores the signed-in user when the page reloads/app restarts, but this requires it to call the server (to check a.o. whether the account was disabled) and that may take some time.

This means that the first time your code runs the user may not be signed in yet, and you need to check for that in your code. It's a bit unclear exactly where in your code the problem occurs, but you'll want to wrap that in:

```
if (firebase.auth().currentUser !== null) {
  ...
}
```

Even better would be to react to when the user is signed in or out, which you can do as shown in the first snippet in the documentation on [getting the currently signed in user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user):

```
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";

const auth = getAuth();
onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in, see docs for a list of available properties
    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User
    const uid = user.uid;
    // ...
  } else {
    // User is signed out
    // ...
  }
});
```

Comment: nope.. your answer was helpful. But how can make the user signed-in as soon as the apps load?